# Jekyll Serve argument error "Option name hard_wrap is already used"

Tags: jekyll, kramdown, jekyll-theme

When I try and run `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I get the error:

- Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Markdown encountered an error while converting. Option name hard_wrap is already used.
- /.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.0/lib/kramdown/options.rb:52:in `define': Option name hard_wrap is already used (ArgumentError)

```
 Generating... 
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Markdown encountered an error while converting '_posts/lunch-and-learn.markdown':
                    Option name hard_wrap is already used
Traceback (most recent call last):
    46: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    45: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    44: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    43: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    42: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    41: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    40: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    39: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    38: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    37: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
    36: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
    35: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
    34: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
    33: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
    32: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    31: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:71:in `process'
    30: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:191:in `render'
    29: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:462:in `render_docs'
    28: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:462:in `each_value'
    27: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:463:in `block in render_docs'
    26: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:463:in `each'
    25: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:464:in `block (2 levels) in render_docs'
    24: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:479:in `render_regenerated'
    23: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:62:in `run'
    22: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:83:in `render_document'
    21: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `convert'
    20: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `reduce'
    19: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `each'
    18: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:101:in `block in convert'
    17: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:76:in `convert'
    16: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:12:in `setup'
    15: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:34:in `get_processor'
    14: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:34:in `new'
    13: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown/kramdown_parser.rb:21:in `initialize'
    12: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/converters/markdown/kramdown_parser.rb:57:in `load_dependencies'
    11: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:55:in `require_with_graceful_fail'
    10: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:55:in `each'
     9: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:58:in `block in require_with_graceful_fail'
     8: from /Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:58:in `require'
     7: from /Users/adam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0/lib/kramdown-parser-gfm.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/adam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0/lib/kramdown-parser-gfm.rb:10:in `require_relative'
     5: from /Users/adam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0/lib/kramdown/parser/gfm.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/adam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0/lib/kramdown/parser/gfm.rb:13:in `require_relative'
     3: from /Users/adam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0/lib/kramdown/parser/gfm/options.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/adam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0/lib/kramdown/parser/gfm/options.rb:11:in `<module:Kramdown>'
     1: from /Users/adam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0/lib/kramdown/parser/gfm/options.rb:13:in `<module:Options>'
/Users/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/kramdown-2.3.0/lib/kramdown/options.rb:52:in `define': Option name hard_wrap is already used (ArgumentError)
```

I'm on version 3.9.0 of Jekyll and I have kramdown-parser-gfm in my gemfile.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will you show the full Ruby error traceback?

Comment: @iBug - just updated the post above with that info.  Thank you!